# rails console in not accepting the commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7

Rails console is loading but not accepting any commands .I am unable to even close the console by typing the exit command.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> ^C
irb(main):001:0> ^C
irb(main):001:0>
```

I have ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x64-mingw-ucrt] version

Answer (score 0):

Typing `exit` and pressing Enter will exit the console.

`irb(main):001:0> exit`

IRB pocket reference here which may help: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ruby-pocket-reference/9780596514815/ch01s27.html

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I am unable to type the letters in the console

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're typing ctrl+C, which will cancel a process that is currently running. To exit the console type ctrl+D

Comment: I am unable to type the letters in the console. The only thing that's appearing is when I pressed ctrl+c as shown above

Answer (score 0):

There could be some environment issues as well, like if the environment is not correctly set up then the console may not work as expected or you can also try to  specify the environment using the command rails console production or rails console development

& also try to check the database.yml there could be some issue there as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).